# Does Dawn awaken creatures sleeping because of magic or poison?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The 0th level druid spell Dawn awakens all sleeping creatures in a 15' radius.  How does this affect creatures that are sleeping because of magical effects or poison?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the condition or effect mandates otherwise

## The Spell *Dawn* Wakens the Sleeping Creatures

The 0th-level Drd spell *dawn* [abjur] (*SpC* 59) says that

> All sleeping creatures in the affected area awaken. Those who are unconscious because of nonlethal damage wake up and are staggered. This spell does not affect dying creatures.

The spell *dawn*, then, is effective *versus* creatures affected by magical sleep effects like that of the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell *[sleep](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/sleep.htm)* [ench] (*PH* 280) and also poisons that cause sleep.

Note that while in earlier editions drow poison was called *drow* sleep *poison*, in *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* drow poison (*DMG* 297) causes unconsciousness (*sans* nonlethal damage), which is unaffected by the spell *dawn*.

Answer (score 2):

> [slapping or wounding awakens an affected creature, but normal noise does not.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/sleep.htm)

Since *sleep* says nothing about what happens when a spell tries to wake up a magially asleep creature, *dawn*'s text does what is written and wakes up the creature.

Poisons like drow's poisoned arrows are a little different. They make the target fall unconscious and you need a Temp save, not a Will one to resist.
While this does not prevent *dawn* from waking up a sleep-poisoned character, I would house rule that toxins keep letting the targer asleep after the instant effect of the *dawn* spell.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the spell is clear about that ("ALL sleeping creatures") but IMO, I think that only the 'naturally' sleeping creatures should awake.
Somebody effected by some magical effect/poison should not awake at dawn if the effect still active.

*PS : Sorry if my English is not really good (I'm French)*

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Your English is perfectly good. :)

Comment: Quite good, but I'm not sure about perfect. The use of the future tense here (“will awake,” “will not awake”) implies certainty, but in reality you seem to be proposing a houserule, in which case *should* would be more appropriate (“only the ‘naturally’ sleeping creatures *should* wake,” “affected by some magical effect/poison *should not* wake”). Also, “at dawn” means “when the sun comes up,” when you mean “what you cast the *dawn* spell.” There are some other minor points, but I wanted mostly just to cover the things that could lead to misunderstanding, not nit-pick.

Comment: @KRyan You are right : my answer is an interpretation and 'should' were more appropriate. Thank you ^^  About the "at dawn", I meant "when the sun comes up" : the spell is cast by a Druid or a Ranger, a 'Nature Caster', so I think the spell should have the same effect on creature that the real event (the sun doesn't comes up but the creature should awake like this is happening).